# How to add claim profile in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I made a claim jwt whose contents are based on UserViewModelLogin.cs, this is Dto. How can I make claim jwt from profilemodels.cs

Controller

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserViewModelLogin userViewModelLogin)
        {
            var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userViewModelLogin.Username.ToLower(), userViewModelLogin.Password, userViewModelLogin.Role);

            if (userFromRepo == null)
                return Unauthorized("Maaf Username atau Password Anda Salah :(");

            var claims = new[]
            {

                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.IdUser.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userFromRepo.Role),
                new Claim("IdProfile", userFromRepo.IdProfile.ToString()),

            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            var role = userFromRepo.Role.ToString();

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
            });
        }
```

UserViewModelLogin

```
public class UserViewModelLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

}
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public int IdProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

Profile Model

```
[Key]
        public int IdProfile { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }       
        public int KTPNumber { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int NumberPhone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int Province_id { get; set; }
        public int Regencies_id { get; set; }
        public int District_id { get; set; }
        public int Villages_id { get; set; }

        public ProfileModel()
       {          
         this.Created = DateTime.Now;
       }
    }
```

I have two models, usermodels.cs and profilemodels.cs, then the user login and generates jwt token output. here I want to the token claims jwt contain profile data from profilemodels.cs.

Comment: what is your problem ?  Just read data from database , mapping to `profilemodels` , and add claims .

Answer (score 0):

You already have

```
new Claim("IdProfile", userFromRepo.IdProfile.ToString()),
```

Then simply add below it

```
new Claim("FullName", userFromRepo.FullName.ToString()),
new Claim("KTPNumber", userFromRepo.KTPNumber.ToString()),
.....
```